# mod_rewrite not altering LESS file location in the document, direct URL is altered however

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, less

I'm trying to pass LESS files over to a PHP compiler via mod_rewrite - when a LESS file is requested, the file should be redirected to the PHP script, passing it's path/name so a CSS file can be spat out.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less.css" />
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/
RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.less)$ compilers/lessphp.php?file=$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Starting out, there is only a .less file.

Refreshing 'http://mydomain.com/v2/' will result in unstyled content. No .css file is created in /styles/.

If I go to 'http://mydomain.com/v2/styles/main.less' I'll be redirected to my PHP compiler 'http://mydomain.com/v2/compilers/lessphp.php?file=styles/main.less', and 'main.less.css' is created as it should within /styles/. Returning to 'http://mydomain.com/v2/', I now have styled content.

Rewrites are only occurring in the URL bar of the browser, not the page of the site.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Is there also a better way to do what I am trying to do?

EDIT2:

/v2/

--index.php

--.htaccess

--/styles/

----main.less

----main.less.css

--/compilers/

----lessphp.php

Comment: where is the htaccess file and where is the page that has the `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />` links?

Comment: See edit2. Again, the rewrite works fine if you put the URL (`mydomain.com/styles/main.less`) into the browser window. LESS file is redirected to the PHP page (`http://mydomain.com/v2/compilers/lessphp.php?file=styles/main.less`) and css file is generated. It's not working if you just go to index.php, where the LESS file is simply `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.less)$ $1.css [R,L,NC]` wont even change `styles/main.less` to `styles/main.less.css`, unless again you put it in the address bar... The page itself will not display the rewritten location/name...

Comment: `#RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.jpg$ $1.gif` works fine to alter `test.jpg` in some HTML to `test.gif`. What's the difference?! Is it the location in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Figured out the issue. Dead simple really.

Playing around with altering extensions and what not, trying to figure out why images would change freely, yet CSS was not, when it struck me that it might have something to do with file type or what not. This is when I noticed the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />
```

`rel="stylesheet/less"` is the culprit here, and is used by less.js for client side rendering. Replacing simply with `rel="stylesheet"` like a normal CSS document, Everything. Just. Worked.

---

Edit: I've written a run through to get Lessphp working properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12274628/1455709)

Answer (score 0):

What happens right now is your browser requests the second link before the compilation is finished and your web server returns 404 because the `*.less.css` file is not there yet.

A better way to do it would be to have your PHP script output the compilation result (e.g. actual CSS) as a response. Whether or not it also produces a `*.less.css` file is irrelevant, though you probably do want to cache your CSS output so LESS is not compiled on every request.

In other words:

- `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />` redirects via mod_rewrite to `compilers/lessphp.php?file=styles/mail.less`
- the above script returns the actual compiled CSS as HTTP response
- the second `<link>` is no longer needed at all

Comment: It's not just a matter of it not being there yet, the compilation never occurs. If I delete the compiled CSS file, and only have `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less" />` in my HTML for instance, refresh the page, `main.less.css` is never created in the /styles/ directory.